# PHP Oauth 1.0 provider, signatures do not match

Tags: php, oauth

I am trying to setup an Oauth server using the pecl-php oauth library http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php

This code assumes that the client has already received a user verified access token, for simplicity sake I've not included any database calls and have hardcoded matching values into my client and provider.

```
Class OauthVerify
{
   private static $consumer_secret = 'f63ed7f7a8899e59d3848085c9668a0d';
   private static $token_secret = '72814e6059441037152eecef2e8559a748b84259';
   private $provider;

   public function __construct()
{
    $this->provider = new OAuthProvider();
    $this->provider->consumerHandler(array($this,'consumerHandler'));
    $this->provider->timestampNonceHandler(array($this,'timestampNonceHandler'));
    $this->provider->tokenHandler(array($this,'checkAccessToken'));

} 

  //Check the client request

   public function checkRequest()
{
    try {
        $this->provider->checkOAuthRequest();
    } catch (Exception $Exception) {
        return OAuthProvider::reportProblem($Exception);

    }
    return true;
}


   public static function timestampNonceHandler($Provider)
{
     //I'm leaving out this logic now, to keep it simple and for testing purposes
     return OAUTH_OK;
}

  public static function consumerHandler($Provider)
{
    //I'm leaving out this logic now, to keep it simple and for testing purposes

    $Provider->consumer_secret = self::$consumer_secret;
    return OAUTH_OK;
}

  public static function checkAccessToken($Provider)
{
    $Provider->token_secret = self::$token_secret;
    return OAUTH_OK;
}
}
```

The above code should give me the barebones I need to authenticate an Oauth request. 
Before any particular route is executed I call the $OauthVerify->checkRequest() method which checks if the client request is valid, however the server keeps throwing a 'signatures do not match' error. I don't think that the problem is with the clients as I've tried both postman (for chrome) and a PHP implementation and they both generate the same signature. I have however for interest sake included my client call.

```
$consumer_key = '87d6d61e87f0e30d8747810ae40041d1';
$consumer_secret = 'f63ed7f7a8899e59d3848085c9668a0d';
$token= 'b9d55b3ec4b755d3fe25d7a781da1dfd044b5155';
$token_secret = '72814e6059441037152eecef2e8559a748b84259';
$timestamp = '1417515075';
$nonce = '9QV4rn';
$version = '1.0';

$method = 'GET';
$url = 'https://localhost/micro/v1/nappi';

try {
     $oauth = new OAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,       OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
     $oauth->enableDebug();
     $oauth->disableSSLChecks();
     $oauth->setNonce($nonce);
     $oauth->setTimestamp($timestamp);
     $oauth->setToken($token, $token_secret);
     $oauth->setVersion($version);
     $oauth->fetch("$url");
     $json = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());
     print_r($json);
 }
    catch(OAuthException $E) {
        print_r($E);
 }
```

I've burned a good couple of hours trying to figure this out, someone please help!

Comment: The problem is definitely with the uri information that OAuth provider is using to generate the signature. If I place the the code in a static php file within the web root, it works perfectly. However I'm using a MVC framework and routes are not literal. I've tried manually setting the uri and http method in the checkOAuthRequest method like so: `$this->provider->checkOAuthRequest('https://localhost/micro/v1/nappi',OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET);` according to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/oauthprovider.checkoauthrequest.php) but still it is not working in the context of a framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it, my .htaccess file had a rewrite rule that was processing a _url parameter for my framework. This parameter was ofcourse being included in the signature that the server generated. I simply instructed OAuth Provider to ignore the the _url parameter in my constructor: 
`$this->provider->setParam('_url',NULL);`, 
that was all it took, everything runs perfectly now.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. though I don't see an extra _url parameter, I am still not getting what is causing the signatures to mismatch. Is there any way that you can see what is the signature on server side and what params are being user to generate that signature ?